# 1C платформа: как перенести макет с одной конфигурации в другую?

Tags: 1с

Есть две конфигурации в 1с: одна бухгалтерия, другая чистая. Есть какой-нибудь способ чтобы копировать некоторые макеты из одной конфигурации в другую, не идентичную? Чтобы не создавать заново формы счетов, товарных накладных и тд, а просто взять их из другой конфигурации и вставить.

Comment: может просто выгрузить конфигурацию из одной и загрузить в другую и поменять то, что нужно?

Comment: мне нужно взять всего 3 макета: счет, реализацию и поступление. а первая конфиг.огромная:)) я затрачу много времени, проще будет с нуля сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно, как минимум, можно воспользоваться [сравнением конфигураций](http://v8.1c.ru/overview/Term_000000291.htm)
Так же можно создать внешнюю обработку, перетащить макет туда и, открыв в нужной конфигурации - перенести

Если нужно перенести один объект конфигурации в другой, поступить можно следующим образом:

1. Открыть обе конфигурации
2. В конфигурации-источнике, выделяем нужный нам документ `(Ctrl+C)`
3. В конфигурации-приемнике, встаем на корень всех документов `(Ctr+V)`
4. Так же можно перетащить мышкой из одной конфигурации в другую

Comment: Спасибо :) сейчас буду пробовать эти варианты

Comment: А можно поподробнее, как перенести документ во внешнюю обработку?

Comment: Ваш вопрос был про макеты, не так ли? :) А вам, значит целиком объект конфигурации "документ" надо перенести? Тогда надо правильно формулировать вопрос )

Comment: @Elena Я дополнил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо)) получилось)) странно, почему-то этот самый простой способ я и не попробовала изначально

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Если ответ подходит, отметьте его как решенный )